# Problem in using JQuery's clone() for text box

Tags: jquery, clone

This is what i need to clone:

```
<p id="ex">
<label for="c2">Enter your Choice</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="c2_r" id="c2" value="" />
<br> 
</p>
```

I clone it by this statement:

```
$("#def").append($("#ex").clone());
```

As i see, it is cloning the p element. But,i actually want it to clone the p tag and set the value of textbox inside it to "". Can someone explain me what to do ? Also, i need to set the id of the textbox inside cloned element to be different from the original . Please help. Thanks

Comment: Does `$('#ex').clone().appendTo('#def');` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// first we grab the clone. We also want to change the <p>'s id, as it's
// not valid to have two elements within a page with the same ID.
$('#ex').clone().attr({
  id: 'newpid' // paragraph's ID
// next, we alter the input inside it (change ID, clear value).
}).find('input').attr({
  value: '',
  id: 'newid' // <input>'s ID
// call end to stop the ".find", then add it to the #def element
}).end().appendTo('#def');
```

Working Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/F4rRQ/1/

Comment: It doesnt work for me . What happens is , it sets the original textbox value to the clone's textbox value. It is weird. I tested it by sending the values of both the textbox to a php file and printing it there

Comment: This is happening on the jsFiddle link I provided? It's 100% working for me, and on that fiddle page. Can you maybe explain a bit more and I'll see if I can fix it up? (or make a jsfiddle of your own with what you have so I can test against it?)

Comment: Okay. I am actually adding and removing textboxes dynamically to a form. When the user clicks an add button, it will add a new textbox along with the label. If the user clicks the remove button, it should remove the textbox that was added last. The problem is when i click add, a new textbox gets added, but its value is "" when i print it in a php file. Also, when i click remove, both the original textbox and the cloned textbox get removed. I set the id value as u indicated for the cloned textbox, but still when i click remove button, both the textboxes disappear

Comment: @hari: Perhaps [this updated version](http://www.jsfiddle.net/F4rRQ/2/) is what you're looking for? (I bound the actions to buttons to show the add/removal, and also used a variable to keep track)

Comment: Not a problem. Feel free to thank me by clicking the checkbox/accept next to this answer though. And welcome to StackOverflow! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
var clonedP = $('#ex').clone();

clonedP
 .attr({ id: 'new_id' })
 .find('input')
  .attr({id: 'new_input_id'})
  .val('');

$('#def').append(clonedP);
```

I put code in place to change their `id` attribute, because an `id` must be unique per page.

You will also need to change the `name` attribute (i.e. different names for different inputs) if you are intending to read this data in a sane fashion.

Comment: Hi ... Does this work for a simple text box ?? I just have to replace 'textarea' with 'text' right?

Comment: @hari Whoops, your title threw me off. I'll amend.

Comment: Hi,it didnt work. I dont know why. Everything is right with the code. But, still both the textbox get the same value